# getJSON and HTTPS

Tags: jquery, json

The following code works great locally.

```
        $.getJSON("/SiteCount/getHistogramData",  
                    {histType: 'Teacher', statusKey:3}, 
                  function(data){  
                      chart_3.dataProvider = data;
                      chart_3.categoryField = "OnHour";

                      var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                      graph.valueField = "Totals";
                      graph.type = "column";

                      var categoryAxis = chart_3.categoryAxis;
                      categoryAxis.autoGridCount = false;
                      categoryAxis.gridCount = data.length;
                      categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";
                      categoryAxis.labelRotation = 90;

                      graph.fillAlphas = 0.8;
                      chart_3.angle = 30;
                      chart_3.depth3D = 15;
                      graph.balloonText = "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>";

                      chart_3.addGraph(graph);

                      chart_3.validateData();

                      if (data.length == 0) {
                          $("#chartdivInProgress").html("<br/><br/><br/><center><b>No Data Submitted in last 5 days!</b></center><br/><br/><br/>");
                      } else {
                          chart_3.write('chartdivInProgress');
                      }

                  });
```

As you can see the return is successful when run locally and my charts work as expected.

[image: Successful on Local]

Notice the type:

```
application/json
```

However, when I move the same code to a **SECURED** machine that is using HTTPS I get the following:

[image: Failure on HTTPS]

Notice the type:

> text/html

The jQuery and the AMChart.js files are all on the same server as the page so it isn't like I'm referencing anything from a non-secured location.  Is there something I need to add to `.getJSON`?

Comment: the thing i see first in the second call is the fact that it is a 404 error, the `type` is irrelevant if it's a 404.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key thing here is not the response type, but the fact you're receiving a 404 error, which happens to be formatted in html.  This error means that the resource you're requesting can not be found.

This could be caused by a number of things, so make sure your secured server is set up correctly.

Comment: yup this was it.  thank you for your observation.  The issue was it was going to the root of the directory.  I had a /Sitecount/getHistorgramData...  Once I took the slash off it worked as I expected.